# Viewer lines in License.licx breaking build process

Tags: c#, wpf, licensing, build-process, activereports

I've recently been tasked with adding a report to an older WPF application.  Part of the process involved adding ActiveReports to the solution in question.

After getting the report implemented and tested on my local machine, it came time to commit it up to our Dev/Test build environments.  Everything went fine, until I attempted to run the application on a machine that did not have ActiveReports installed and licensed on it - I got the "Viewer needs to be licensed error window."

Here's where things get confusing, though.  It should be working.

For starters, I'm running ActiveReports `8.0.133.0`.

The contents of my `licenses.licx` file are:

```
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff
```

I've generated a satellite licensing DLL for the WPF project's executable, and ensured that it's referenced and set to `Copy Local = true`.  ([I've already dealt with this in the past.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210035/licenseexception-for-sectionreports-activereports-7-0-6158-0?rq=1))

Even though it's not a web project, for safety's sake, I used the WebKey Generator and added an `Active Report 8 Developer` key to the `app.config` file.

It gets more interesting, though.  When I add the following lines to my `licenses.licx` file, as the error window I get above suggests I should do:

```
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Wpf.Viewer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Wpf.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff
```

When I try to simply *build the project in Dev*, the build fails with the following message:

```
[10:29:34]     [exec] (CompileLicxFiles target) -> 
[10:29:34]     [exec]   Properties\licenses.licx(2): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: License cannot be confirmed. Error code: 01-001 [C:\CheckoutDirectory\Project\[(0) BUILD]\UI\UI.csproj]
[10:29:34]     [exec]   Properties\licenses.licx(3): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Wpf.Viewer, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Wpf.v8, Version=8.0.133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: License cannot be confirmed. Error code: 01-001 [C:\CheckoutDirectory\Project\[(0) BUILD]\UI\UI.csproj]
```

For those who don't want to scroll:

```
System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: License cannot be confirmed. Error code: 01-001
```

The end result is a sort of Morton's Fork of badness.  Either I can build the app, but I can't run the report (which, is sort of the point of me making these changes), or I simply can't build the app at all.

**Question:** What can I do to get the report viewer to run without a license exception *and* keep the application building?  I should also note, I'm on a short deadline with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was correct to add the Win and WPF viewer lines; it turns out the answer was to upgrade the Build server with Active Reports 8.  From there, everything went swimmingly.

TL;DR - Upgrade everything that needs to be upgraded!